# Issue in displaying pop-up div over target element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to display a popup div onMouseHover on the image. Currently, the pop is displayed under the scroll bar. I need to display this a floating popup type over the scroll bar of the div instead of hidding beneath the scroll bar.

Thanks in advance!

**Sample Code:**

**CSS**

```
.popBox {
        margin: -50px 50px 0px 50px;
        z-index: 2;
        width: 60px;
        padding: 0.3em;
        border: 1px solid gray;
    }
.images {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
div.scroll {
    background-color: #00FFFF;
    width:80px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
</style>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
  function showBox(text, obj) {
        helpNode = document.createElement('div');
        helpNode.id = 'popBox';
        helpNode.setAttribute('class','popBox');
        helpNode.innerHTML = text;
        obj.appendChild(helpNode);
  }

  function hideBox() {
        node = document.getElementById('popBox');
        node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
  }
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<body>

<div class="scroll" style="margin:0px auto">
 <b onMouseOver="showBox('<b>Foo1</b><br /> Bar1', this)" onmouseout="hideBox()" ><input type="image" class="images"  src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-511058.jpg" /></b></br>
    <b onMouseOver="showBox('<b>Foo2</b><br /> Bar2', this)" onmouseout="hideBox()" ><input type="image" class="images"  src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-380016.jpg" /></b></br>
    <b onMouseOver="showBox('<b>Foo3</b><br /> Bar3', this)" onmouseout="hideBox()" ><input type="image" class="images"   src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-293063.jpg" /></b></br>
    <b onMouseOver="showBox('<b>Foo4</b><br /> Bar4', this)" onmouseout="hideBox()" ><input type="image" class="images"   src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-611834.jpg" /></b></br>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try adding position: absolute; to .popBox ?

Comment: Or appending it to an element outside the scroll area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding position: absolute; to .popBox

CSS

```
.popBox {
    margin: -50px 50px 0px 50px;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 60px;
    padding: 0.3em;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    position: absolute;
    }
.images {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }
div.scroll {
    background-color: #00FFFF;
    width:80px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
    }
```

JavaScript

```
  function showBox(text, obj) {
        helpNode = document.createElement('div');
        helpNode.id = 'popBox';
        helpNode.setAttribute('class','popBox');
        helpNode.innerHTML = text;
        obj.appendChild(helpNode);
  }

  function hideBox() {
        node = document.getElementById('popBox');
        node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
  }
```

HTML

```
<div class="scroll" style="margin:0px auto">
    <b onMouseOver="showBox('<b>Foo1</b><br /> Bar1', this)" onmouseout="hideBox()" ><input type="image" class="images"  src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-511058.jpg" /></b></br>
    <b onMouseOver="showBox('<b>Foo2</b><br /> Bar2', this)" onmouseout="hideBox()" ><input type="image" class="images"  src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-380016.jpg" /></b></br>
    <b onMouseOver="showBox('<b>Foo3</b><br /> Bar3', this)" onmouseout="hideBox()" ><input type="image" class="images"   src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-293063.jpg" /></b></br>
    <b onMouseOver="showBox('<b>Foo4</b><br /> Bar4', this)" onmouseout="hideBox()" ><input type="image" class="images"   src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-611834.jpg" /></b></br>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/digiman07/xb3faw6g/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in fiddle and it doesn't work for me, so something must be missing, but to handle your CSS issues, you need to add a position to the z-index'd elements. So, in your case would be like this:

```
div.scroll {
background-color: #00FFFF;
width:180px;
height: 200px;
overflow: scroll;
position:relative;
z-index:-1
}
```

This way, that pop out will be over the scrollbar.

Also, as we're at it, replace `</br>` by `<br/>` or simply add `.images{display:block}`

Comment: I tried it in a fiddle and got the same result, however, copying it to an HTML file did work.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to append the nodes outside of the element that has `overflow: scroll` applied to it. By it's nature, `overflow: scroll` will make your popups need scrolling to see.

You'll probably want to add another wrapper div around the element, and give it `position: relative`, append your popups to that new wrapper div, and position them with `position: absolute` (the `position: relative` on the new wrapper div makes the absolutely positioned children positioned absolutely relative to that element.)